# How can I add a folder or file to the root in a recipe with bitbake?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to put a folder into the root of the filesystem. In the documentation (e.g. [here](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#understanding-recipe-syntax)) they use mostly variables and so the files and folders from `SRC_URI` result in being stored under `/usr/bin` or something but never in `/`.

So here is my recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Example for adding files and folders to rootfs"

SRC_URI += "file://example_folder"
SRC_URI += "file://example_file"

LICENSE = [...]

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/rootfolder
    cp -r ${WORKDIR}/example_folder ${D]/rootfolder/
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/example_file ${D}/rootfolder
}
```

This is just one of very many `do_install` variants that I tried.Every of them resulted in either `Error: example not found in the base feeds [...]` or that the files and folders haven't been placed in the root but in `/usr/bin` as explained above.

Comment: Do you have that recipes layer included in your conf/bblayers.conf? Your error seems unrelated to the other issue you state of the files ending up in the wrong place. If you want to really modify the base file system I think I would suggest doing a bbappend on top of the base-files recipe.

Comment: @Joe I wouldn't have errors regarding the recipe if I wouldn't have done that. There is everything configured accurately except the `do_install` task has mistakes.

Comment: Which recipe would that be?

Comment: "Error: example not found in the base feeds" is usually bblayers.conf related, that was all.

Comment: A `.bbappend` for adding files to rootfs would be appreciated, but how can I do that?

Comment: Are you based off poky? If so it has a meta/recipes-core/base-files recipe.

Comment: @Joe Yes I am using freescale SDK. I studied the base-files recipe now a bit: Can I make references on the dirsXXXX variables now from a bbappend? Or how is it typically done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the cases were you get the error "Error: example not found in the base feeds [...]" it's quite likely that you actually have succeeded in building your recipe example.bb. Assuming of course, that you get that error when building your image, which has `IMAGE_INSTALL += "example"` in it.

If you install your files into `/rootfolder`, there's nothing in OE itself that knows how to package those files into an `rpm`, `ipk`, or `deb` package. You need to add that yourself to your recipe by adding a line like:
`FILES_${PN} += "/rootfolder"`

Doing that, your example above should work.

Depending on what files you install, you might want to add some of them to other packages like `${PN}-dbg`, `${PN}-dev`, etc.

Comment: Update: Just a new mistake at another place trying to reproduce. your answer really helped. thank you very much.